# How to resize plot while keeping subplot ratio in subplot2grid?

Tags: python, subplot

I have the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import gridspec

df = {'date': ['2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05'],
      'donkey': [5,2,3,3,5],
      'monkey': [1,3,5,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,5))

axes[0] = plt.subplot2grid((1,2), (0,0), colspan=1)
axes[0].set_title('Donkey Feet', size='x-large')
axes[0].plot(df.date, df.donkey, marker='', color='orange', linewidth=4, alpha=0.7)

axes[0] = plt.subplot2grid((1,2), (0,1), colspan=1)
axes[0].set_title('Monkey Nasalfold', size='x-large')
axes[0].plot(df.date, df.monkey, marker='', color='orange', linewidth=4, alpha=0.7)
```

I want to change the plot size while maintaining its grid boundary like the picture. I searched for answers but could not find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, if you start the range of the y-axis with a negative value, you get the following graph.

```
axes[0].plot(df.date, df.monkey, marker='', color='orange', linewidth=4, alpha=0.7)
axes[0].set_ylim([-4,5.5])
```

[image]